# Proving that the square root of all integer non perfect squares is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was doing a number problem as homework about proving that the square root of all integer non perfect squares are irrational. I have proven that it is true for all primes, using Euler’s lemma. However I am not sure how to approach this problem for all integer non perfect squares. Any help or solution would be appreciated very much! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I want to know how to prove it’s irrational not whether it must be either integer or irrational number.

Comment: The Rational Root Theorem or the method of infinite descent can be used to prove any integer that isn't a perfect square has an irrational square root.

Comment: Please do not repost the exact same question which was closed as a duplicate. The answer to your question is there. It’s integer when it’s root of perfect square. Irrational otherwise.